# Running diagnostics on a multivariate multiple regression in r

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I have a data set that gives the rates of incidence of some phenomena in all the zip codes of a state, and some demographic data. The rates are given for each year in the data set (year 1 - year 6). A snippet of the data is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwntjvazaoxblkk/snippet.xlsx?dl=0).

I've run a multivariate linear regression to examine the impact of the demographic variables on the rates, per Fox & Weisberg (2011), weighted by the average zip code population across all years (`var = POPmean`):

```
Y <- cbind(data$rateY1, data$rateY2, data$rateY3, data$rateY4, data$rateY5, data$rateY6)

model <- lm(Y ~ someVAR1+someVAR2+someVAR3+someVAR4+someVAR5, data=data, weights= POPmean)

summary(model)
coef(model) 
summary(manova(model))
```

I'd like to plot the regression diagnostics for this model for each year, but have no idea how to do so. I'd like to use `influencePlot()` from the `car` package, but when I try to do so:

```
influencePlot(model, id.method="noteworthy", main="Robustness Check")
```

I receive an error stating that the lengths of x,y differ (which, of course, they do). Can anyone help figure out how to plot the regression diagnostics for the model given above? Or suggest an alternative method?

Comment: one (incomplete) possibility: reshape the data (e.g. `reshape2::melt`) and then use `nlme::lmList` or `lme4::lmList` (this will only give you basic diagnostics, e.g. residuals and Q-Q plots -- not influence plots ...)

Comment: When I try to run this model `TESTmodel <- lmList(Y ~ someVAR1+someVAR2..., data=data, weights= pop mean)` I get the following error: `Error in modelFormula(formula) : 
  rhs of formula must be a conditioning expression`. Not sure what I'm making the model conditional on...